# Build a PDF from a template in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I would like to create a template in doc, pdf, odt, docx ... document type does not matter.
What I want is to get this document, change some values ​​and convert this document to PDF.

For example:

Take this template:

```
<Title>
<Date>

Hello <Name>,

<Text>

         <Farewell>
```

And with this information:

```
Title: attention
Date: 22/05/2011
Name: NicosKaralis
Text: Lorem ipsum ...
Farewell: See you later
```

generate this pdf document, using color, background and anything that may have the template:

```
attention
22/05/2011

Hello NicosKaralis,

Lorem ipsum ....

         See you later.
```

There are any way to do this in Ruby on Rails?
preferably using prawn

Thanks in advance

**-- EDIT --**

1 The owner of the application will create something like this: [Original.(odt, doc, pdf)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oOh6d68--aWx03YlE8aZq_o5YqNZJAqszyFEo83_gec/edit?hl=pt_BR)

2 My app database will have a user with this attributes:

> title = Welcome to the internet!
>
> name = Jhon Doe
>
> text = Welcome to the internet, i will be your guide
>
> farewell = Hope to see you soon!

3 My app will create a pdf like this: [Final.pdf](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iRLdnqBjZ2E1H99SfrExz-H65ckkhoIkEJD1kMYdktI/edit?hl=pt_BR) and send it by email

The email part i already have working. I just don`t have the pdf.

> P.S.: I now how to create a pdf from scratch, but i dont want that.
>   The point of this application is that you don`t need to be a rails
>   developer to change the pdf that is generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with prawnto, but I'm pretty familiar with prawn. Since version 0.10.1 they've had the ability to import another pdf for use as a "template" per se. If you check the [new manual](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf) there's a section on templates. If you look at the page titled templates/page_template.rb you'll see some example code. It takes some text and positions it manually, but there may be a way to do some sort of actual substitution.

Comment: On second thought, you could create a Prawn::Text::Box that's the same color as your background then place that over your template tags. Then place the substituted text on top of that box. I don't believe there's really an easy way to do this.

Comment: well ...
This manual explains a bit about templates, but what I really wanted was to change the PDF without having to hacking on the code. And I do not think that text box will load the formatting from template. thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, from what I've found there's no good/easy way to do this. If you have a couple grand for the license there is a commercial library PrinceXML that apparently will convert XML/HTML with CSS to PDF. That may be the easiest way, but expensive. If your clients can create actual PDF Template you might check into this, http://forums.adobe.com/thread/740262

Comment: that won't help... the final user of this application doesn't now anything of xml/html/css. i found a way to change the xml inside a .odt file, but i'm still looking at it.

Comment: Not being particularly familiar with .odt and .doc formats I can't say for sure, but there's probably a gem out there (or a native function of the programs that deal with them) that will convert them to html/xml with css. From there you could pretty easily do your text substitution and then pass it to PrinceXML. But again, ~$4000 for a server license may be the real barrier here.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/sandrods/odf-report#readme) may address the first half of the problem.  Then use something like [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) to generate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice screencast from Ryan Bates [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/78-generating-pdf-documents) explaining the trick with PDF::Writer. I think that's what you want :)

Comment: I have seen this screencast, but it does not fit in my needs

Comment: you will make and save a document as a document (doc, odt, pdf, doesn't matter). will send it to me. I'll put in my rails application. my rails app will create a PDF using document as your template. User information with the my rails app will create a PDF and will send via email to the User.
I do not know how to be more precise.
- Client generates pdf.
- Rails application the document fills in of the client with the User information and generates a pdf.
I just need it, use a document that already exists, and build a new which I can change some information.